# How to save current chart in ChartPanel as PNG programmatically?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have created a `JFreeChart` in a `ChartPanel` and I want to save it programmatically. The functionality should exist as it is possible to do this manually (right click menu and `PNG` option from there).

I found the method `chartPanel.createImage(??, ??)`, but I don't know what `width` and `height` I need to set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was to use a method `ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG`

**Example:**

```
try {

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(chartName);
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out,
            aJFreeChart,
            aChartPanel.getWidth(),
            aChartPanel.getHeight());

} catch (IOException ex) {
    logger.error(ex);
}
```

Comment: Why not one of the `ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG()` variations?

Comment: At the version 1.5.0 the classe ChartUtilities changed to  org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils;

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can do this:

```
public static void exportAsPNG throws IOException {
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());


    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(600, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

    g2.setRenderingHint(JFreeChart.KEY_SUPPRESS_SHADOW_GENERATION, true);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
    chart.draw(g2, r);
    File f = new File("/tmp/PNGTimeSeriesChartDemo1.png");



    BufferedImage chartImage = chart.createBufferedImage( 600, 400, null); 
    ImageIO.write( chartImage, "png", f ); 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the advantage of your answer over the accepted, embedded one?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to version 1.5 use `ChartUtilities` class

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(<File>, chart, width, height);
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(<OutputStream>, chart, width, height);
```

With version 1.5 JFreeChart renamed `ChartUtilities` class to `ChartUtils`. It offers the same functionality.

```
ChartUtils.saveChartAsPNG(<File>, chart, width, height);
ChartUtils.writeChartAsPNG(<OutputStream>, chart, width, height);
```

Please note that there are more variants of those methods.